# How can I select with exception in mySQL

Tags: mysql

SELECT department FROM myTable WHERE contact IS NULL

```
   Department    Contact
    ------------- ---------
    Cleaning      Jack
    Admin         Peter
    Software      James
    Cleaning      (null)
    Cleaning      Jill
    Hardware      (null)
```

In the table above, how can I select department where contact is null excluding existed contact.

The statement above 
will return "Cleaning" and "Hardware".

What I expected is only "Hardware"

How can I select only "hardware" or is it possible.

TIA

Comment: `WHERE contact IS NULL AND departement = 'Hardware'` ..?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to only return rows which do not have any non-null contacts.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT department
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    contact IS NULL
    AND department NOT IN (SELECT department FROM myTable where contact IS NOT NULL)
```

or, if you want to do it without the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.[department]
FROM
    myTable AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    myTable AS b
        ON b.[department] = a.[department]
        AND b.[contact] IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    a.[contact] IS NULL
    AND b.[contact] IS NULL
```

self join using `NOT NULL` for the condition, then verify the `JOIN` failed by checking for `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: My answer got in a few seconds earlier, but yours has better formatting. It's a toss-up.

Comment: @octern nah, you can have it :D I'm going to try and redo it without the `NOT IN`

Comment: I'll be interested to see how you do that! I know subqueries are considered less elegant than self-joins so there's probably a better solution out there.

Comment: @octern tada! not sure which will be more efficient... will depend on his data/schema

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to exclude departments that are associated with a non-null value in ANY record. To do this, you should do a subquery to get all non-null departments, and exclude them from your query that retrieves null departments. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department
FROM mytable
WHERE contact is null 
AND department NOT IN (SELECT department FROM mytable where contact is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT department,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Contact is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count
         from myTable
         group by department
         HAVING count > 0 ;
```

Comment: still no good, this checks for `NULL` departments, not contacts... then requires a second step for eliminating.

Comment: that is my mistake i did that

Comment: @Matthew see my answer once

Comment: @Matthew did you check my answer once